# Show seems to forget 'logness' for Ticks of LogLogPlot

Tags: plotting, labeling, logarithmic-scale

So there is a `(List)LogLogPlot` I made a few months ago. Now, it turns out the axes I had back then are too small. Now, the creation of these plots costed quite some calculational time. So, instead of doing everything again, I execute

```
Show[*Paste old graph*,AxesStyle->Large,ImageSize->500]
```

Which kind of does what I expected it to do. The problem is, due to the increased size of my Tick-numbers, they overlap on the horizontal axis.
So I want to reduce these labels from the default

```
{10,50,100,500,1000,5000,10000}
```

to

```
xlist={10,100,1000,10000}.
```

When I specify `Ticks->{{xlist},{ylist}}`

All ticks seem to dissapear (actually, one on the y-axis seems to remain, it is hard to read but it looks like it is in the wrong place).

When i specify `Ticks->Automatic`, ticks appear at natural numbers with even spacing, as if it were a normal plot instead of a LogLogPlot. The same behaviour when only the y-axis is set to automatic.

**MWE:** an example of this appears as well when comparing for example

```
LogLogPlot[10000/T^2, {T, 10, 10000}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed},Ticks->Automatic, AxesStyle -> Large, ImageSize -> 500]
```

with

```
Show[LogLogPlot[10000/T^2, {T, 10, 10000}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, AxesStyle -> Large, ImageSize -> 500],Ticks->Automatic]
```

**Partial solution:** To large extent, the problem can be solved by setting the graphics option

```
Ticks -> {{{Log[10], 10}, {Log[100], 100}, {Log[1000], 1000}, {Log[10000], 10000}}, Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}]}.
```

The only remaining issue is that this gives only ticks markers at the specified x-values, Whereas the default (Charting`ScaledTicks) draws more unlabeled ticks markers without a label and with varying size. It would be nice to have these too on the x-axis: more ticks-markers with varying size and without label.

It would seem to me this could be obtained by, instead of giving an explicit list in Ticks right away, play with the options of

```
Charting`ScaledTicks
```

which seems undocumented.

```
Options[Charting`ScaledTicks]={Method->Automatic,TicksLength->Automatic,Object->None,Ticks->Automatic}.
```

Giving `Charting` an option like `Ticks->{{Log[10],10},{Log[100],100}}` or even `TicksLength->Large` doesn't seem to make a difference however.

Comment: We're gonna need more data and code to judge.

Comment: @Feyre added MWE

Comment: I'm confused is to why you need the `Show[]`. Presumably you have the data from the graph stored somewhere?

Comment: @Feyre by mistake I haven't. There must be a way to extract the data from the plot using inputform I realize, but I thought there must be a way using show that is less messy. Also, the drawing tools work only inside graph itself, not on its ticks labels.

Comment: You may be interested in `Information[]`.

Comment: @Feyre thanks for the hint. I'm currently trying to identify the piece of code that specifies the Ticks-labels using FullForm.

Comment: @Wouter I'd recommend using `InputForm`, instead, it is a bit easier on the eyes. Also, if you are looking for the options being passed to `Graphics` use `Options`, which is much easier than trying to read through the `InputForm` of the entire thing.

Comment: @rcollyer thanks, I wasn't realizing 'Rule' meant the option arrow :)

Comment: @Wouter `Rule` is it's `FullForm`, i.e. `a -> b` is interpreted as `Rule[a, b]`. It's an important hurdle in understanding how mma processes its input, so keep comparing the `FullForm` to the `InputForm` it will save you from messes like this one: `#[[1]] + 2^#&@#[[2]] &` which got me yesterday. `Plus` has a higher precedence than `Function`, so that this is [interpreted](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) as `(#[[1]] + 2^#)& @ #[[2]]&`. Definitely not what I wanted. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
plot = LogLogPlot[10000/T^2, {T, 10, 10000}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, Ticks -> Automatic, AxesStyle -> Large, 
  ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

```
Show[plot, 
 Ticks -> {Quiet[
     Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][#1, 1.1 #2, {6, 6}]] &, 
   Quiet[Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][#1, #2, {6, 6}]] &}]
```

[image]

How did I do this? Admittedly, by try-and-error. If you do `List @@ plot` you can see all the options that are set of this plot. From there I saw how the ticks are specified and played with the numbers. The first item in the list given to `Ticks` specifies the x-axis ticks. Multiplying the second argument of the mysterios `ScaledTicks` function seems to change how many minor ticks are used between two major ticks. Multiplying this argument by 1.1 seems to lead to a major tick every 10 minor ticks.

Comment: The usage of `ScaledTicks`, while undocumented, appears in [several answers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=ScaledTicks+is%3Aa), The general form is ``Charting`ScaledTicks[<scaling args>][min, max, divisions]``. So your `1.1 #2` trick tells the ticks function that the range is a bit greater at the upper end (in fact, at `T == 29427.3 == Exp[(1.1) (1 + 1/64) Log[10000]]`).  It does seem counterintuitive that increasing the range results in fewer major ticks.

Comment: BTW, you can use just ``Charting`ScaledTicks["Log"]`` for the vertical axis.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the arguments. Just for completeness, let me add that `[<scaling args>] = [{function, inversefunction}, options]`. Also, I found that `divisions = {maximum number of major ticks, number of minor ticks between major ticks}`. So I would expect setting `divisions = {3,11}` would do the job. In fact, changing the first number in divisions produces weird output (try 5 or 21 instead of 6), whereas the second number has absolutely no effect.

Comment: Let's just say I said `<scaling args>` because there are several variants, not just that one. (But that one seems to be the most commonly used one.)

Comment: Good to know. Maybe we should create our own documentation for such officially undocumented functions (maybe as a question "What is the definition of ..."). As it is now, one has to extract the definition and function arguments from a bunch of comments in a variety of questions.

Comment: See `FindDivisions[]` for the `divisions` argument (and its relation to `min`, `max`).  They're basically suggested targets, much as you suggest.