# Control the display unit length of `PlotRange`

Tags: plotting

If I have an example plotted data such as:

```
ListPlot[{{-20, 2}, {-10, 1}, {10, 0.001}, {20, 0.0000001}, {80, 0.000000001}}, PlotRange -> {{-20, 80}, All}]
```

Which plotted gives:

[image]

How can I use `PlotRange` to display the x-axis every 10 units rather than every 20 units as it is by default?

Comment: That's not what `PlotRange` is for. Try adding `Ticks -> {Range[-30, 100, 10], Automatic}` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I use the undocumented `` Charting`ScaledTicks ``  function:

```
ListPlot[
 {{-20, 2}, {-10, 1}, {10, 0.001}, {20, 0.0000001}, {80, 0.000000001}},
 PlotRange -> {{-20, 80}, All},
 Ticks -> {
    Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][-20, 80, {10, 2}], 
    Automatic}
]
```

[image: plot]

What I know about this function I've mostly learned in [the comments to this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135774/27951). In short:

```
Charting`ScaledTicks[{scalingFunction, inverseScalingFunction}][min, max, divisions]
```

where `divisions` can be a number, or `{maximum number of major ticks, number of divisions between each pair of major ticks}`, so the specification I used above asks for labeled major ticks every 10 units, with one minor tick in between each major one (i.e., *two divisions* between each major tick). Note that sometimes the behavior of divisions is quirky; I assume that it uses `FindDivisions` or similar behind the scenes, which always attempts to find "pretty" / "good" divisions according to a heuristic.

Comment: Thank you MarcoB!